# How to set custom permission for buttons or fields in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I wrote a module for **Drupal** and I have some fields (buttons, image, text).

I want that some fields could be hidden for normal users and open for users when admin let.

This feature is implemented using **"Field Permission"** module. I don't know how to write PHP code in my module, so can I change permissions using **"Field Permission"** module?

Answer (score 0):

In your module you can set the #access of those fields depending on roles like:

```
$roleId = The role id;
// If user doesn't have the role he can't access the field .
if (isset($user->roles[$roleId])) {
  // Deny access to the field.
  $form['FIELD_NAME']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```